# Handle small determinants in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to handle determinants close to 0. Is there a way to do this without using if-else statements? The code is below.

```
import numpy as np

array = np.arange(16)
array = array.reshape(4, -1)
determinant = np.linalg.det(array)

print("Determinant is %s" % determinant) 
print("Determinant is %d" % determinant)
print("Determinant is %f" % determinant)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "handle"? What's wrong with determinants that are close to zero?

Comment: I would like the determinants close to 0, to actually be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
determinant = 0 if numpy.isclose(determinant, 0) else determinant
```

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful.